# How to make a button work from another class JAVAFX

Tags: javafx

I've been wondering how to make a button work for a week and I still haven't found a solution.

My main class basically loads all my .fxml files.

rootLayout.fxml - menubar / two buttons / in the centre of a BoardPane is set contentLayout.fxml which consist of TableView.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import vp.dict.model.Data;
import vp.dict.view.ContentController;
import vp.dict.view.EditDialogController;
import vp.dict.view.RootController;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;


public class MainApp extends Application {

    private Stage window;
    private BorderPane rootLayout;

    private ObservableList<Data> dataList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public MainApp(){
        dataList.add(new Data("Hi", "Haj", "Ahoj, cau"));
        dataList.add(new Data("Hello", "Helou", "Ahoj"));
        dataList.add(new Data("New", "Nju", "Novy"));
    }

    public ObservableList<Data> getDataList(){
        return dataList;
    }

    public void start(Stage window) throws IOException {
        this.window = window;
        this.window.setTitle("EN/CZ Dictionary 2017");

        initRootLayout();
        initContent();
    }

    public void initRootLayout() throws IOException{
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("../view/rootLayout.fxml"));
        rootLayout = (BorderPane)loader.load();

        Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
        window.setScene(scene);
        RootController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setMainApp(this);

        window.show();
    }

    public void initContent() throws IOException{
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("../view/contentLayout.fxml"));
        AnchorPane ap = (AnchorPane)loader.load();

        rootLayout.setCenter(ap);
        ContentController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setMainApp(this);

    }

    public boolean showEditWindow(Data data) throws IOException{
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("../view/editDialogLayout.fxml"));
        AnchorPane ap = (AnchorPane)loader.load();

        Stage editWindow = new Stage();
        editWindow.setTitle("Add a New Word");
        editWindow.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
        editWindow.initOwner(window);

        Scene scene = new Scene(ap);
        editWindow.setScene(scene);

        EditDialogController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setStage(editWindow);
        controller.setData(data);

         editWindow.showAndWait();

         return controller.isOkClicked();
    }

    public Stage getWindow(){
        return window;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The content controller is just showing the TableView data

```
package vp.dict.view;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import vp.dict.main.MainApp;
import vp.dict.model.Data;

public class ContentController {

    @FXML
    private TableView<Data> dataTable;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Data, String> englishColumn;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Data, String> pronunciationColumn;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Data, String> meaningColumn;

    private MainApp mainApp;

    public ContentController(){

    }

    @FXML
    public void initialize(){
        englishColumn.setCellValueFactory(CellData -> CellData.getValue().englishProperty());
        pronunciationColumn.setCellValueFactory(CellData -> CellData.getValue().pronunciationProperty());
        meaningColumn.setCellValueFactory(CellData -> CellData.getValue().meaningProperty());
    }

    public void setMainApp(MainApp mainApp){
        this.mainApp = mainApp;

        dataTable.setItems(mainApp.getDataList());
    }

    public TableView<Data> geTableView(){
        return dataTable;
    }
}
```

RootController class is where I need to do the work. Inside the method private void handleDelete() you can see a bit of code in comments which is a working code but I cannot figure out a way to load the data from the ContentController class which is the junk of code above.

```
package vp.dict.view;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.security.auth.login.Configuration;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import vp.dict.main.MainApp;
import vp.dict.model.Data;

public class RootController {

    private MainApp mainApp;

    public void initialize(){

    }

    public RootController(){

    }

    public void setMainApp(MainApp mainApp){
        this.mainApp = mainApp;
    }

    @FXML
    private void addClicked() throws IOException{
        Data tempData = new Data();
        boolean okClicked = mainApp.showEditWindow(tempData);
        if(okClicked){
            mainApp.getDataList().add(tempData);
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleDelete() throws IOException{



      /*  int selectedIndex = contentTable.geTableView().getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
        if (selectedIndex >= 0) {
            contentTable.geTableView().getItems().remove(selectedIndex);
        } else {
            // Nothing selected.
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.WARNING);
            alert.initOwner(mainApp.getWindow());
            alert.setTitle("No Selection");
            alert.setHeaderText("No Person Selected");
            alert.setContentText("Please select a person in the table.");

            alert.showAndWait();
        }*/
    }       
}
```

I'll appreciety any ideas on how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you cannot reach `ContentController` from `RootController` because you do not have any reference between these two. Secondly, it would probably be more neat to let `ContentController` handle it, while `RootController` would simply do the informing.

### Edit

Okay, I messed up the execution order a little here. This is the correct one.

MainApp:

```
private void RootController rootController;

...

// In initRoot()
this.rootController = loader.getController();

// Replace the below line in initContent():
//ContentController controller = loader.getController();
//controller.setMainApp(this);
ContentController controller = loader.getController();
controller.setMainApp(this);
this.rootController.setContentController(controller);
```

RootController:

```
private ContentController contentController;
public void setContentController(ContentController content)
{
    this.contentController = content;
}

...

@FXML
private void handleDelete() throws IOException
{
    if (this.contentController != null)
        this.contentController.handleDelete();
}
```

ContentController:

```
public void handleDelete()
{
    // Whatever delete logic you originally had here
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I exactly followed your steps but something seems to be wrong. Whenever I click the button 'Remove' which refers to the 'handleDelete()' nothing happens. I  also added an extra println statement to make sure I'm not doing anything wrong but it doesn't print anything.

Comment: By the way, if I remove the 'if statement in RootController if (this.contentController != null)' I get this error message http://pastebin.com/J2sYtRQV

Comment: @Jiri Updated. I messed up the order that the code executes.

Comment: Thank your for your help. Yesterday, I asked a friend of mine to help me out and he figured out a way to make it work. The issue was in MainApp. He had to merge RootController with ContentController to make it work. Another solution would be to add and EventListener to ContentController.